# Giving sizes to the widget and drawing in it

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to create a widget with a fixed size and background. It is to be added first in BoxLayout. I would like to draw a line inside this widget so that it is visible only in it and placed in relation to it.
By entering (0,0) the position of the line I mean the beginning of the widget and not the entire application window.
How to achieve this effect?

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class CombWidget(Widget):
    pass

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CombWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

and kv file

```
<CombWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size
        padding: 20
        spacing: 50

        MyPaintWidget:
            size: 400, 400
            size_hint: 400, 400

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
                Line:
                    points: 0, 0, 200, 200


        Button:
            text: "Hallo"
        Button:
            text: "Hallo 1"
        Button:
            text: "Hallo 2"
```

Right now I have something like this:
[image]

But I would like to get something like this:
[image]

I would like to be able to draw only in this widget and provide positions of the drawn elements in relation to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adjust the `points` of the `Line`:

```
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Line:
                points: self.x, self.y, self.x + 200, self.y + 200
```

Comment: Works, thank you very much! Could additionaly suggest how I can draw on this widget giving percentages?
For example, I would like to draw 10 lines on it at an equal distance from each other. I don't know how do this.

Comment: To draw 10 lines, just use the `Line: points:`, as above, 10 times. And you can use simple arithmetic to calculate the points.